# how to use Vlfeat in Octave in window 7?

Tags: ubuntu, image-processing, computer-vision, octave, vlfeat

I use octave and want to use Vlfeat to do my project in Windows 7. The website has suggestion to use from Octave as below:

[image]

I complete to install package image according to the code in green (first) box. However, I've got stuck to the code in red (second) box. Is the code in red box used in Octave or in Windows command prompt? If No, Where should I use it? Is it in Ubuntu command prompt? I am not accustomed to Ubuntu. To use it without Ubuntu would be much appreciated (Although I have some sense that it definitely is related to Ubuntu) but if it unavoidable for Ubuntu, could anyone suggest me how.

Yesterday, I tried to use the red code in Ubuntu, Windows, Octave and it all got somehow error for a whole day. I thought the code is for Ubuntu but the code start with '>' not '$' so I'm not sure anymore. The website doesn't suggest enough information and doesn't have discussion forum. I got lost now.

Anyone please help me :<

---

The picture below is the result according to the suggestion from Unapiedra. Could someone tell me about the error?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code in the second box is meant to be executed by the command line.

Under Windows you would have to replace `cd` with `chdir` and you would need `make` installed.

You also need to find where `mkoctfile` is located on Windows and provide that information to make like it is done in the example.

## Compiling on Windows

There is also good information on how to compile on Windows on the VLfeat website [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/compiling-windows.html). Try that first, and add the `MKOCTFILE` parameter as well. (You might have to edit it into the NMake file. )

## Conclusion

It doesn't seem like there is a proper option. Compilation under Windows is done using NMake. The configuration of this is in `Makefile.mak`, the configuration for UNIX is in `Makefile` which in turn loads (among others) `make/octave.mak`. There is no provision for Octave in the Windows `Makefile.mak`.

Options:

1. Fix it yourself. It shouldn't be too hard. Just compare what is done to Matlab under Windows, see what is done to Octave under UNIX and change the Windows makefiles to compile the Octave API. (Ideally, open a pull request on VLfeat's Github with the working code.)
2. Ask the main author of VLFeat for some help. I've contacted him in the past with bug fixes and he was responsive to that.

Duplicate (unanswered): [Running VLFeat setup using OCTAVE (OS: Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391974/running-vlfeat-setup-using-octave-os-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: I download 'Make' from this link --> http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm Is it correct? And I execute 'Make' and in window command prompt, I use the command as you suggest, but the error occur as the picture above. Can you advise me more, please?